# Is There a Problem with my Nightwatch.conf.js file?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have been attempting to setup an automated testing framework for my job, and nodejs testing has seemed to be the best option for future scalability. Plus, I am attempting to stretch myself into new areas of QA.

I have setup my Nightwatch framework with npm install commands and manually installed the most up-to-date chrome drivers, and selenium standalone executables. I have attempted to ensure that my nightwatch.conf.js file is completely setup to run my first test with google chrome, but I get this error:

```
⚠ Error connecting to localhost on port 4444.
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution; 0 tests failed, 0 passed (249ms)

 ✖ GoogleTest
   An error occurred while retrieving a new session
Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

  Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session
       at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

   SKIPPED:
   - Basic Google search
```

Which seems to be pretty generic. As per normal Nightwatch setup, I created a root folder called 'Automation' where I stuck my bin folder for the drivers and selenium framework. Inside of the 'Automation' folder I also have my nightwatch.conf.js file that I've setup (Let me know if its more helpful if I paste its code in here). In order to run my test, I use the **npx nightwatch** command, but I continue to get this error.

From what I can tell it may be due to me trying to run the tests locally, but I can't think of a way that I would configure the selenium service to accept local ports other than how it's been setup.

I don't know if this is a well formatted description of the problem, so I apologize in advance if this is super vague. If there's anything else I can do to help clear it up let me know.

Thank you!

**Update** Conf.js File

```
// Autogenerated by Nightwatch
// Refer to the online docs for more details: https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/
const Services = {}; loadServices();

module.exports = {
  // An array of folders (excluding subfolders) where your tests are located;
  // if this is not specified, the test source must be passed as the second argument to the test runner.
  src_folders: ["tests"],

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/working-with-page-objects/
  page_objects_path: '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/extending-nightwatch/#writing-custom-commands
  custom_commands_path:  '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/extending-nightwatch/#writing-custom-assertions
  custom_assertions_path: '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#external-globals
  globals_path : '',

  webdriver: {},

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      disable_error_log: false,
      launch_url: 'https://nightwatchjs.org',

      screenshots: {
        enabled: false,
        path: 'screens',
        on_failure: true
      },

      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName : 'chrome'
      },

      webdriver: {
          start_process: true,
          server_path: (Services.chromedriver ? Services.chromedriver.path : '.Automation/bin/chromedriver.exe')
      }
    },

    safari: {
      desiredCapabilities : {
        browserName : 'safari',
        alwaysMatch: {
          acceptInsecureCerts: false
        }
      },
      webdriver: {
        port: 4444,
        start_process: true,
        server_path: '/usr/bin/safaridriver'
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities : {
        browserName : 'firefox',
        alwaysMatch: {
          // Enable this if you encounter unexpected SSL certificate errors in Firefox
          // acceptInsecureCerts: true,
          'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: [
              // '-headless',
              // '-verbose'
            ],
          }
        }
      },
      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 4444,
        server_path: (Services.geckodriver ? Services.geckodriver.path : './Automation/bin/geckodriver.exe'),
        cli_args: [
          // very verbose geckodriver logs
          // '-vv'
        ]
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities : {
        browserName : 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          // This tells Chromedriver to run using the legacy JSONWire protocol (not required in Chrome 78)
          w3c: true,
          //More info on Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
            args: ['disable-gpu', 'no-sandbox', 'headless']
        }
      },

      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 9515,
        server_path: (Services.chromedriver ? Services.chromedriver.path : './Automation/bin/chromedriver.exe'),
        cli_args: [
          // --verbose
        ]
      }
    },

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Configuration for when using the browserstack.com cloud service               |
    //                                                                               |
    // Please set the username and access key by setting the environment variables:  |
    // - BROWSERSTACK_USER                                                           |
    // - BROWSERSTACK_KEY                                                            |
    // .env files are supported                                                      |
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    browserstack: {
      selenium: {
        host: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com',
        port: 443
      },
      // More info on configuring capabilities can be found on:
      // https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities?tag=selenium-4
      desiredCapabilities: {
        'bstack:options' : {
          local: 'false',
          userName: '${BROWSERSTACK_USER}',
          accessKey: '${BROWSERSTACK_KEY}',
        }
      },

      disable_error_log: true,
      webdriver: {
        keep_alive: true,
        start_process: false
      }
    },

    'browserstack.chrome': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          // This tells Chromedriver to run using the legacy JSONWire protocol
          // More info on Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
            w3c: true,
            args: ['disable-gpu', 'no-sandbox', 'headless']
        }
      }
    },

    'browserstack.firefox': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
      }
    },

    'browserstack.ie': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'IE',
        browserVersion: '11.0',
        'bstack:options' : {
          os: 'Windows',
          osVersion: '10',
          local: 'false',
          seleniumVersion: '3.5.2',
          resolution: '1366x768'
        }
      }
    },

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Configuration for when using the Selenium service, either locally or remote,  |
    //  like Selenium Grid                                                           |
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    selenium: {
      // Selenium Server is running locally and is managed by Nightwatch
      selenium: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 4444,
            server_path: (Services.seleniumServer ? Services.seleniumServer.path : './Automation/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar'),
        cli_args: {
          'webdriver.gecko.driver': (Services.geckodriver ? Services.geckodriver.path : './Automation/bin/geckodriver.exe'),
          'webdriver.chrome.driver': (Services.chromedriver ? Services.chromedriver.path : './Automation/bin/chromedriver.exe')
        }
      }
    },

    'selenium.chrome': {
      extends: 'selenium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
            w3c: true,
            args: ['disable-gpu', 'no-sandbox', 'headless']
        }
      }
    },

    'selenium.firefox': {
      extends: 'selenium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
          args: [
            // '-headless',
            // '-verbose'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function loadServices() {
  try {
    Services.seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');
  } catch (err) {}

  try {
    Services.chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
  } catch (err) {}

  try {
    Services.geckodriver = require('geckodriver');
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `Nightwatch.conf.js` file and also your project structure ?

Comment: Sure thing. My nightwatch is located in ./node_modules/nightwatch and my project folder for my tests are ./Automation/tests, ./Automation/reports, ./Automation/bin.

My conf.js file is added to the main block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will suggest is to create a create a new file for `Nightwatch.conf.js` and then start adding rest of the configuration from there. Below is an example which works for me:

```
module.exports = {
    src_folders: ["tests"],
    skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
    page_objects_path: "pageObjects",
    custom_commands_path: "./commands",
    screenshots: {
        enabled: true,
        path: "./screenshots",
        on_failure: true,
        on_error: true
    },
    test_settings: {
        default: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                chromeOptions: {
                    prefs: {
                        download: {
                            default_directory: require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/download')
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 4444,
                server_path: require('chromedriver').path,
            }
        },

        test_workers: {
            enabled: true,
            workers: 'auto'
        },

        safari: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'safari',
                alwaysMatch: {
                    acceptInsecureCerts: false
                }
            },
            webdriver: {
                port: 4445,
                start_process: true,
                server_path: '/usr/bin/safaridriver'
            }
        },

        firefox: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            },
            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 4446,
                server_path: require('geckodriver').path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Nightwatch JS, chromedriver, geckodriver are installed using the npm commands. Since I am using a mac I just needed to enable the safari webdriver.

```
npm install nightwatch --save-dev
npm install geckodriver --save-dev
npm install chromedriver --save-dev
safaridriver --enable
```

1. This is the full repo if you want to have a look: https://github.com/alapanme/NightwatchJS
2. Also if you need the detailed steps how I setup Nightwatch on my machine you can refer: https://testersdock.com/nightwatch-js-installation/

Comment: It must have been my configuration file then. I'm not sure what about it was causing the return error I was receiving, but after some configuration of the source folder locations, your file worked and my tests are running! I'll do some extra research with the links you've provided, but this is a great first step for me. Thank you!